# Getting Razor data inserted into src and href attributes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe, razor, umbraco

I need to insert an API key and a location string into the src attribute of my iframe element.

This is how my iframe looks atm:

```
<iframe class="center-block" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=@Umbraco.Field('aPIKey')&q=@Umbraco.Field('lokation')" width="95%" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But when i go to the page, i get this error:

```
Too many characters in character literal
```

I tried using "" instead for the razor properties, but that destroys the formatting for the rest of the dokument.

I'm just really confused as to what is the correct way to use Razor syntax inside HTML attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Umbraco.Field('lokation') @Umbraco.Field('aPIKey')
```

should be

```
@Umbraco.Field("lokation") @Umbraco.Field("aPIKey")
```

The `'` quote is used for character literals in `c#`

Now because you are using `"` quotes in razor you will need to change the html quotes to be `'`.

```
<iframe class="center-block" src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=@Umbraco.Field("aPIKey")&q=@Umbraco.Field("lokation")' width="95%" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, as it doesn't format correctly. http://i.imgur.com/5oDCDK2.png

Comment: Great, I'd appreciate it if you could mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `@(Umbraco.Field("lokation"))` - if your "variable" includes parantheses or other special characters such as " when you're already inside a ""-delimited text string, you need to encase the whole thing in ... more parantheses :-)